# When selecting line in VS Code with the shortcut Ctr+i, cursor jumps to the line below. How to avoid it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When selecting line in VS Code with the shortcut `Ctr+i`, the cursor jumps to the line below.

Meaning if i press copy, it actually copies two lines...

Is there a way to force the cursor to stay at the end of the selected line?

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.action.smartSelect.grow
```

seems to do what you want with some number of keypresses unfortunately.  It is already bound to <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> but you ca rebind that command to something else less cumbersome.

Comment: but that only selects the right part of where my cursor is, i want to select the whole line no matter where my cursor is

Comment: While holding down the shift-alt, keep hitting the rightarrow.  You'll get the whole line.